# Mode local variables

Tags: minor-mode, file-local-variables, symbols

I frequently use file-local variables, but after writing some minor modes I find the need to implement mode-based behavior.

Let's say I want to define a variable `errors-list-regexp` that varies depending on the major mode.

My first approach was to ask major modes to define such a variable by using a symbol-name convention, by prefixing the major mode name onto the variable name. Then, I would construct the appropriate symbol name, check whether it is bound and if so obtain its value (for example, `java-mode-errors-list-regexp` or "python-mode-errors-lisp-regexp")
But this is a bit cumbersome:

```
(let* (
       (sym (intern (concat (symbol-name major-mode) "-errors-list-regexp")))
       (errors-list-regexp (and (boundp sym) (symbol-value sym)))
       )
  ...
  )
```

Another solution might be to turn the variable into a (mode . value) alist, but this also is too cumbersome.

```
(let* (
       (errors-list-regexp-value (cdr (assoc major-mode errors-list-regexp)))
       )
  ...
  )
```

My current approach is to make `errors-list-regexp` buffer local, and to add a major-mode-hook (say, to java-mode-hook or python-mode-hook) that sets the appropriate mode-specific value.

I'm mostly satisfied with the latter solution but, is there a better way? Is this idiomatic?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I realize I was a bit vague about which modes I was talking about, so I edited to clarify. I'm writing a minor mode, which uses variables whose values differ across major-modes. My goal is to assign a value to these based on the major mode. But yeah, I think I understand. Care to add that as an answer?

Comment: OK, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make the variable buffer-local, and turn the mode on in a given buffer, to use it. Your code can of course test whether the mode is on in a given buffer.